# Check values on mysql table and select ones that are set to "1"

Tags: php, mysql

I looked all over. I cannot figure this out.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!empty($_POST[username]))
{
    require_once("connect.php");

    // Check if he has the right info.
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members
                            WHERE username = '$_POST[username]'
                            AND password = '$_POST[password]'")
    or die ("Error - Couldn't login user.");

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query)
    or die ("Error - Couldn't login user.");

    if (!empty($row[username])) // he got it.
    {
        $_SESSION[username] = $row[username];
        echo "Welcome $_POST[username]! You've been successfully logged in.";
        exit();
    }
    else // bad info.
    {
        echo "Error - Couldn't login user.<br /><br />
            Please try again.";
        exit();
    }

    if($isadmin["admin"]==1)
{
echo $admin;
}
else
{
}

}

$admin = <<<XYZ
<div id="admintab">
Admin &nbsp;&#0187;
<div id="admin">
ADMIN PANEL
<div id="exitadmin">
</div>
<div id="artistline" />
</div>
</div>
XYZ;

?>
```

I do know that the `$admin` value is working. I have tested it. Basically, I have a register system. By default, it sets your admin value to '0'. But let's say i want to add an admin. I change the '0' to a '1' via mysql. I want to know how to make php find users with their admin value set to '1' that are in the database (row name: admin), and display the admin panel to them only.

Comment: where you have defined `$isadmin['admin']`

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, XSS attacks and passwords are not being hashed.  You've managed to show a perfect example of how not to implement a login system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `if($isadmin["admin"]==1)` to `if($row['admin'] == 1)` -- you can leave out the `== 1` part if 1 & 0 are the only answers as 1 will always be true and 0 will be false.

Obligitarily, I need to mention that storing passwords in your database in plain text is a bad idea, you should be at the very least hashing them before you store them. Something like `$password = hash('sha256', $salt.$_POST['password'])` at the registration and login stages.

I should also point out that you shouldn't feed naked values into your database with a query, you don't need to worry about password if you're hashing it, but you do if you're not and you need to do username anyway otherwise anyone can run SQL queries in your database:

`$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])`

Comment: which is best `md5` or `sha256` ?

Comment: `sha256` is far better than `md5` if you run once. Very secure systems use things like `bcrypt` which is blowfish (I think) based but with added hardening and multiple hashes.

Comment: @Oshwott but according to me md5 cant be decrypt

Comment: md5 can't be decrypted, that's true, it's a one way hashing function. However it's much easier to make brute-force attacks against md5 than against sha256 or bcrypt.

Comment: I always use `bcrypt` in a production environment, personally, but it does have high overheads.

Comment: i will also apply it in future production

Comment: The hashing works, thank you, but now I'm getting errors on the anti-injection part of the code:

 Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\users\insert.php on line 10

Line 10: $eusername = mysqli_real_escape_string( $_POST['username'] );


$sql="INSERT INTO users (username, password, email)
VALUES
('$eusername','$hpassword','$eemail')";

Comment: @TrevorZucker, `mysqli` functions when used procedurally always have to be passed a connection object explicitly. My example used `mysql_real_escape_string` which is for the now-deprecated mysql library.

Answer (score 1):

Why have you used

`if($isadmin["admin"]==1)`

as you have

`$row = mysql_fetch_array($query)`

so convert

`if($isadmin["admin"]==1)`

to

`if($row["admin"]==1)`

you should check the value before insert and select the data and also use

`mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])`

so that sql injection not apply

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I am obligated to point out that not filtering $_POST (and $_GET and $_COOKIE and so on) is very dangerous, because of SQL injection. Secondly, the variable $isadmin doesn't magically exist until you've defined it.

I would suggest designing a more capable user group system, but just to answer the question, the variable you want to check is $row["is_admin"], given that is_admin is a valid column in the table. Also, you don't need to do if ($row["is_admin"] == 1) - 1 evaluates to TRUE in PHP.